# Docker not loading class path

Tags: java, mysql, docker

I'm trying to connect to a remote hosted mysql ,but docker run is not loading driver, gives `classnotfounderror`.

```
ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
appreciate help! thanks.
```

--

```
FROM java:8-jdk-alpine
RUN apk get update 
RUN apk --no-cache add curl
RUN curl -L -o /mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.34/mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar
COPY . /tmp
WORKDIR /tmp
EXPOSE 3307 3306
CMD ["java","-classpath","mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:.","com.smartworks.JavaMySQLConnection"]
```

Comment: Your mysql connector jar is downloaded to filesystem root, `/`, not to your workdir

Answer (score 3):

found answer. thought helpful for others. thanks everyone for their contribution.

```
FROM openjdk
COPY src . 
COPY target/mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar libs/
ENV CLASSPATH=libs/mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:${CLASSPATH}
RUN javac /*.java
ENTRYPOINT ["java","RDSConnectionTest"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your mysql connector jar file is output to root `/mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar` by curl command.

So when you reference it in java command with `-classpath`, you should use the same path `/`mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar

```
CMD ["java","-classpath","/mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:.","com.smartworks.JavaMySQLConnection"]
```

So why not directly output to /tmp by `curl` command, if that is what you need

```
FROM java:8-jdk-alpine
RUN apk --update --no-cache add curl
RUN curl -L -o /tmp/mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.34/mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar
WORKDIR /tmp
EXPOSE 3307 3306
CMD ["java","-classpath","mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:.","com.smartworks.JavaMySQLConnection"]
```

Comment: unfortunately that didnt work. ive changed your docker instruction as follows since i need to copy test file. still getting same error. help appreicated ! thanks.           ```FROM java:8-jdk-alpine
RUN apk --update --no-cache add curl
RUN curl -L -o /tmp/mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.34/mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar
COPY JavaMySQLConnection.java /tmp
WORKDIR /tmp
RUN javac JavaMySQLConnection.java
EXPOSE 3307 3306
CMD ["java","-classpath","mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar:.","JavaMySQLConnection"]  ```

Comment: (however if i create a manifest file with connector jar included and run java jar it is working fine. but that is not the solution i am looking forward to..